# spring security oauth2 authorization server without any UI

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, microservices

I have implemented a spring security oauth2 authorization server as a spring boot microservice.  I'm trying to allow our main (non-java) application to migrate to oauth2 using this new service.

One thing I can't get around my head is how to set this up so that the authorization server never shows any UI.  In particular, is there any way to have the /oauth/authorize UI hosted on our main application, but still accept proxied authorization approvals?  Or does that UI need to be served directly by the authorization server?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a login page in your UI app, the login will call the authentication server like:

```
curl -X POST -vu client:secret http://localhost:8081/spring-security-oauth-server/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=password&username=user&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=secret&client_id=client"
```

You will receive a access token that will be used to access the endpoints in your resource server like:

```
curl http://localhost:8081/spring-security-oauth-resource/path/endpoint -H "Authorization: Bearer <Token>"
```

Comment: Thanks- Yes that's the Resource Owner Password Grant- i'm using that for login.  I was talking about supporting the authorization code grant in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

The UI for login does NOT need to be on the Authorization Server (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3 Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant). This leaves it up to the client to collect the credentials and make a direct token request to the Authorization Server.

However, I don't generally recommend bypassing the AS UI as it means that each client application will have to implement a login logic and you won't get single sign-on between those client applications.

Comment: Thanks- I'm not talking about the login UI I'm talking about the authorize UI. The "authorize app to access your email address" part of the authorization code grant flow.

Comment: I don't think you can use the authorization code grant flow and use your app UI. If you don't want to see the authorization page you can automatically approve scopes. See https://github.com/sdoxsee/jhipster-with-external-authserver/blob/master/authserver/src/main/java/demo/AuthserverApplication.java#L115 for example. Why would you want to host this on your client application?

Comment: I'm trying to create the authorization service as a microservice and was hoping to host the UI in our "main" UI application.  The autoapprove might be a suitable workaround.